# ¿Por qué no encuentra el objeto en el array?

Tags: javascript, array, angular, typescript

Estoy tratando de validar si mi array ya contiene el elemto con indexOf y siempre me devuelve -1 ¿qué estoy haciendo mal ?

```js
addToList(product:any){
    let add = this.productsSelected.indexOf(product);
    console.log(add);
    console.log(this.productsSelected);
    console.log(product);
    if(add == -1){
      this.productsSelected.push(product);
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.productsSelected);
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    }else console.log("el producto ya se ha agregado");
  }
```

esta es la resuesta por consola

[image]
Como pueden ver siempre devuelve -1 indicando que el objeto no está pero está 3 veces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema de `indexOf` es que usa el operador === para comprobar si el elemento existe. Esto hace que sólo funcione con tipos *básicos*: number, string y boolean.
Cuando intentas comparar objetos, esto no funciona porque dos instancias son siempre objetos diferentes, aunque sus propiedades sean iguales. Por tanto, deberías cambiar `indexOf` por otro método, como `findIndex`, que recibe como parámetro la función que comprueba si el elemento es el que buscas:

```js
class Dato {
  constructor(d) { this.dato = d; }
  
  toString() { return "Dato " + this.dato; }
}

let arrayDeDatos = [];
for (let i = 0; i<5; i++) {
  arrayDeDatos.push(new Dato(i));
}

//comprobamos que tenemos 5 objetos
console.log("datos en el array:", arrayDeDatos.toString());

let dato2 = new Dato(2); //generamos un objeto nuevo
let dato2Real = arrayDeDatos[2]; //aquí tenemos el mismo que en el array

//diferentes instancias con mismos valores
console.log("Comparando con ===", arrayDeDatos[2].toString(), dato2.toString(), arrayDeDatos[2] === dato2);
console.log("usando indexOf", arrayDeDatos.indexOf(dato2));

//misma instancia
console.log("Comparando con === usando la misma instancia nos da ", arrayDeDatos[2].toString(), dato2Real.toString(), arrayDeDatos[2] === dato2Real);
console.log("usando indexOf con la misma instancia nos da ", arrayDeDatos.indexOf(dato2Real));

let resultado = arrayDeDatos.find(item => item.dato === dato2.dato);
console.log("usando find", resultado.toString());

resultado = arrayDeDatos.findIndex(item => item.dato === dato2.dato);
console.log("usando findIndex", resultado);
```

Comment: Sabes que tengo otro methodo casi igual pero es para eliminar objetos del array osea de la lista de la foto de arriba. Y ahí con indexof si me arroja el índice correcto a qué de debe esto ? Gracias de antemano  y gracias por tu respuesta

Comment: Puede ser porque estás comparando el objeto consigo mismo, actualizo la respuesta para que lo veas

Answer (score 1):

> Por lo que mostras te interesa agregar un objeto si este  no se
> encuentra en un array de objetos entonces podes utilizar some(..)
> a modo de ejemplo en js Agregue un objeto duplicado en productos solo
> por si también te interesa ver si productos contiene duplicados
>
> ```js
> const productos = [
>     {
>         "id": "1",
>         "name": "vino",
>
>     },
>     {
>         "id": 2,
>         "name": "aceite",
>
>     },
>     {
>         "id": "1",
>         "name": "vino",
>
>     },
> ]
>
> const produtAgrega =
> {
>     "id": 2,
>     "name": "aceite",
>
> }
>
> addToList(productos, produtAgrega);
>
> function addToList(productos, agrega) {
>
>
>
>     // para no agregar  un duplicado con
>     if (productos.some(e => e.id === agrega.id)) {
>         console.log('el producto ya se encuentra')
>     }
>     // para contralar si tu array de productos contiene duplicados con:
>     const ver = productos.reduce((a, e) => {
>         a[e.id] = ++a[e.id] || 0;
>         return a;
>     }, {});
>     console.log('productos  duplicados', productos.filter(e => ver[e.id]));
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```js
idSeleccionados=[]
productos=[]

addToList(producto){
  
   if(!this.idSeleccionados.includes(producto.id) {
      this.idSeleccionados.push(producto.id)
      this.productos.push(producto)
   }
}
```

Otra alternativa es crear un arreglo que contenga un id de los elementos seleccionados: