# obtener posicion de un objeto dentro de un array

Tags: javascript, array, json, position

Tengo un array que contiene dentro unos objetos, cada objeto solo tiene elementos "concepto, area.

```
let miArray = [{concepto:"examen", area:"matematicas",
                concepto:"practico", area:"matematicas",
                concepto:"tarea", area:"matematicas"}]
```

Lo que intento es que, teniendo una valor de "concepto" obtener la posicion de ese objeto en mi vector. Hay alguna funcion como **indexOf** pero para objetos?

La otra forma seria recorrerlo con un foreach preguntando en cada iteracion, pero quizas exista una manera mas facil

Comment: Puedes leer el siguiente enlace, puedes usar un find o un filter https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/javascript-filter-array-of-objects-based-on-property

Comment: El problema es que find o filter te devuelven el objeto entero, lo que yo necesito es la posicion de ese objeto en el array

Comment: Relacionada o quizá duplicada, pero esta pregunta me parece mejor planteada que la que enlazo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/499961/por-qu%c3%a9-no-encuentra-el-objeto-en-el-array, así que me abstengo de cerrarla... quizá sea incluso mejor cerrar la otra como duplicada de ésta :)

Comment: Eso sí, cuando tengas dudas sobre si existe una función, te recomiendo consultar [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#instance_methods)

Comment: Tu `miArray` no vendría siendo `{concepto:"examen", area:"matematicas"}, {concepto:"practico", area:"matematicas"}, {concepto:"tarea", area:"matematicas"},`  o sea 3 objetos dentro de un array (cada uno separado por `{ }`, porque como lo muestras en el código es como si fuera 1 solo objeto dentro del array.

Comment: Si es como creo que es entonces la respuesta de @Legna funciona perfectamente, usando `findIndex`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Puedes utilizar [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) para lo que deseas hacer:

```js
let miArray = [{
    concepto: "examen",
    area: "matematicas"
  },
  {
    concepto: "practico",
    area: "matematicas"
  },
  {
    concepto: "tarea",
    area: "matematicas"
  },

]


let index = miArray.findIndex(x => x.concepto === 'tarea')
console.log(index)
```

## Acerca de [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

> El método `findIndex()` devuelve el índice del primer elemento de un
> array que cumpla con la función de prueba proporcionada. En caso
> contrario devuelve `-1`.

---

### Nota aclaratoria

Nota que la estructura de tus datos en la pregunta tiene un error. La forma en que está escrita la pregunta solo contiene un elemento, puesto que un objeto que recibe las mismas llaves sobre escribe los datos.

```js
let miArray = [{
  concepto: "examen",
  area: "matematicas",
  concepto: "practico",
  area: "matematicas",
  concepto: "tarea",
  area: "matematicas"
}]


console.log(miArray)
```